# DocumentFormat for OpenXML

Tags: vb.net, openxml

I'm trying to create an Excel file to save using OpenXML and I've found some guidelines on Microsoft website, talking about declaration of OpenXML through importing modules. I added at the beginning of the code:

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
```

I'm having back three warnings, each per line: `BC40056 Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.` Besides, I'm also having issues while compiling the code itself, because every time I recall DocumentFormat, I receive back an error about "not declared" variable. Which could be the problem? Thanks in advance all are gonna answer me.

Comment: You can't use types that your project doesn't know exist. You have to actually reference the library in which the type is declared. It's also of no use importing a namespace that has no types declared either in your project or in a referenced library. I suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/12/referencing-assemblies-and-importing.html).

Comment: Note that there are also third-party libraries, often available as NuGet packages, that make working with OpenXML simpler that using it directly.

Comment: Ok I've downloaded NuGet package about DocumentFormat for OpenXML.